# Select values from one columns based on values from another column - python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe `df1` that looks like this:

```
DeviceID     Location
1            Internal
1            External   
2            Internal   
2            Internal   
3            Internal   
3            External   
3            Internal
4            Internal   
4            Internal
5            External   
5            Internal
```

I'm trying to find and select the rows where a single `DeviceID` is recorded with both "Internal" AND "External" values in the `Location` column.

The next step would be to drop these rows from the dataframe.  The final dataframe `df2` would look like so:

```
DeviceID     Location
2            Internal   
2            Internal   
4            Internal   
4            Internal
```

What I've attempted so far is: 
`indexDI = df[(df['Location'] == 'Internal') & df['Location'] == 'External') ].index
df.drop(indexDI, inplace = True)`

but this seems to have to dropped all the rows with "Internal".

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby`, `transform` with the [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) to see which gorups contain two different values and use the result to perform boolean indexing on the dataframe:

```
df[df.groupby('DeviceID').Location.transform('nunique').eq(1)]

     DeviceID  Location
2         2  Internal
3         2  Internal
7         4  Internal
8         4  Internal
```

---

Simple add `reset_index(drop=True)` for a panda's [`RangeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.RangeIndex.html)

Comment: You don't need `.loc`. `reset_index` is not really needed either.

Comment: Yup, though a RangeIndex will presumably be what op wants. But yeah I guess iI'll just add a note @QuangHoang

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to loop through the entire df and drop the rows if both conditions are met. Right now your solution checks the same row which can't have both criteria at once.

Comment: It would be appreciable if you show running example.

Answer (score 0):

one more solution without .loc,

```
df[(df.groupby('DeviceID').transform('nunique')!=2).values]
```

O/P:

```
   DeviceID  Location
2         2  Internal
3         2  Internal
7         4  Internal
8         4  Internal
```